# PHP что такое элемент массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте, только познаю программирование. Элемент массива - это ключ или значение? Или же и то и то (ключ => значение/массив значений (элемент в значении которого элемент и тд.))?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B/info

Comment: Иднекс - ключ, элемент - значение

Answer (score 3):

Можно обратиться к [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php).

В массиве есть индекс (ключ) и элемент, соответствующий ему. Индексы (ключи) могут быть заданы числовым или же символьным значением.

Пример:

```
$array = ['Один', 'Два']; // 'Один' и 'Два' - элементы массива
echo $array[0];

$two = array(
  "Первый" => "Один", // 'Первый' - ключ, 'Один' - элемент массива
  "Второй" => "Два"   // аналогично вышенаписанному
);

echo $two['Первый']; // выведет элемент массива 'Один', которому соответствует ключ 'Первый'
```